# Are rational functions with positive integer coefficients honest?

Tags: complexity-theory, arithmetic

For every rational function $p(x)/q(x)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients, does there exist a polynomial function $h$, such that, if you input a reduced fraction $a/b$ of length $m$ into $p(x)/q(x)$ and the output is of length $n$, then $m\leq h(n)$?

The length can be taken as the number of digits in decimal $a$ plus the number of digits in the decimal b$,$ or any other equivalent, like Kolmogorov complexity.

In other words, does there exist a rational function $p/q$ which keeps shortening fractions by more than a polynomial factor? In fact, it seems to me that it would not shorten fractions by more than a constant factor.

Comment: Contuining: Are there any restrictions on the lengths of $p$ and $q$? <throws up hands in despair>

Comment: Thank you, People, for engaging. By 'length' I mean any sort of informational length like Kolmogorov complexity, but more simply the length of decimal encoding (ie length of reduced fraction $a/b$ is the number of digits of $a +$ the length of the digits of $b$). The length of $p$ and $q$ are fixed of course. The question is to show that any such rational can keep reducing any fractions more than by a polynomial amount.

Comment: I edited the question - should be self-contained now. Apologies - I thought that "honest" is a well-known term in complexity. It appears often in the topic of one-way functions, I think.

Comment: Do you mean "$n\leq h(m)$"? I'd expect the output of a polynomial to be in some sense more complex than the input (e.g., $x^2$ has more digits than $x$).

Comment: Hi David! There was a typo in the original version - the function I am interested in, is rational. I have reworded the question to make it clearer, hopefully.